# terraform output is getting extra content, how to fix that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

terraform output -raw ssh_key

Should give only the ssh key, but getting below output.

[output of terraform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqLPe.png)

Not coming if we use direct terraform but coming with the version installed using [tfenv](https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv).

Executing: /home/vagrant/.tfenv/versions/1.2.5/terraform output -raw ssh_command

Comment: This looks like your private key, which is part of the ssh key. What do you want to output only the public key?

Comment: No sir, if you observe the text above the private key in the image, it should not come generally but coming now.

Comment: Maybe an idea to create an issue on the github of tfenv: https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv/issues

Comment: yeah created there also, https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv/issues/344